# Can't set Rabbit_STOMP port 6163

Tags: centos5, rabbitmq, mcollective

I am trying to setup mcollective using RabbitMQ. Per instruction, I enabled rabbit_stomp plugin and then set the port to 6163:

```
[ {rabbit_stomp, [{tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1",6163}]} ]} ].
```

However, even after a restart, it does not seem to want to set it to that port.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54949               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      13439/beam.smp      
tcp        0      0 :::5672                     :::*                        LISTEN      13439/beam.smp      
tcp        0      0 :::61613                    :::*                        LISTEN      13439/beam.smp
```

in looking through the web, the above code seems to be the appropriate step, so what I am I missing.

I am running the following:

```
[root@trp08-01 rabbitmq]# rpm -qi rabbitmq-server
Name        : rabbitmq-server              Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.8.1                             Vendor: (none)
Release     : 1                             Build Date: Thu 22 Mar 2012 10:52:25 AM EDT
Install Date: Sat 28 Apr 2012 04:33:31 PM EDT      Build Host: release-debian.localdomain
Group       : Development/Libraries         Source RPM: rabbitmq-server-2.8.1-1.src.rpm
Size        : 3320919                          License: MPLv1.1
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Thu 22 Mar 2012 10:55:48 AM EDT, Key ID f7b8cea6056e8e56
URL         : http://www.rabbitmq.com/
Summary     : The RabbitMQ server
Description :
RabbitMQ is an implementation of AMQP, the emerging standard for high
performance enterprise messaging. The RabbitMQ server is a robust and
scalable implementation of an AMQP broker.
[root@trp08-01 rabbitmq]# rpm -qi erlang
Name        : erlang                       Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : R14B                              Vendor: Fedora Project
Release     : 03.3.el5                      Build Date: Sun 07 Aug 2011 06:21:28 AM EDT
Install Date: Fri 27 Apr 2012 10:50:55 AM EDT      Build Host: x86-11.phx2.fedoraproject.org
Group       : Development/Languages         Source RPM: erlang-R14B-03.3.el5.src.rpm
Size        : 31472                            License: ERPL
Signature   : (none)
Packager    : Fedora Project
URL         : http://www.erlang.org
Summary     : General-purpose programming language and runtime environment
Description :
Erlang is a general-purpose programming language and runtime
environment. Erlang has built-in support for concurrency, distribution
and fault tolerance. Erlang is used in several large telecommunication
```

On CentOS 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I should learn to read the documentation more closely:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html

I mis-spelled rabbitmq_stomp. Corrected with:

```
[
  {rabbitmq_stomp, [{tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 6163},
                                     {"::1",       6163}]}]}
].
```

Interestingly enough, the Pro Puppet book had it also as rabbit_stomp. I am not sure if it is an update to the plugin after the book was published or an error with the book itself.

Comment: I also found the misspelled error in the Pro Puppet book. Changed to `rabbitmq_stomp`, restart the `rabbitmq-server`, but it still listen to 61613 port, by the default (not 6163). To be more sure, I also set the `CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` in the `rabbitmq-env.conf`, but it sounds like the rabbitmq-server doesn't read the config file. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Try kill off the erlang process after your stop rabbit. For some reason, that still hangs around even though you stop the services.